Ставится ли перед словом должен запятая?
Кто не сдал тетрадь, должен принести в пн и сдать. Ставится ли запятая?

Правильно:
Кто не сдал тетрадь, (тот) должен принести в пн и сдать.
Пояснение
Запятая ставится в СПП с придаточным местоименно-определительным.
Местоименная пара: (тот) — кто. Указательное слово тот пропущено в разговорном стиле.
